# hola no encuentro mi error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\carrito\calificaciones.php on line 89

Tags: php, html, mysql, web

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\carrito\calificaciones.php on line 89

Esta linea es la ultima en mi código tal vez olvide cerrar algo pero ya revise y no lo veo, el caso es que quiero vaciar mis datos que contenga mi base de datos en la tabla boleta para ser mostrada en una tabla en la página, según el usuario que inicio sesión yo supongo que ya esta bien pero aun no estoy seguro por que me envía ese error y otra consulta quiero que el contenido de esta pagina se muestre en mi `index` al dar click sobre la opción de calificaciones de mi menú espero si alguien sabe como puedo hacer esto díganme ya use `include();` pero solo e arroja el que este dentro del paréntesis si yo quiero elegir otra opción como debo poner que me muestre la opción según elija es decir en mi menú tengo calificaciones y reportes y quiero que me muestre ya sea o calificaciones si elijo en mi menú o reportes no ambas les agradezco mucho su ayuda!

```
<?php session_start();
include "conexion.php";
echo $_SESSION['Usuario'];
?> 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />   
<head>
<link href="csscali.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Calificaciones</title>
<link href="csscali" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<?php

        if(isset($_SESSION['Usuario'])){
            $re=mysql_query("select * from user_alumno where CURP='".$_POST['id']."'")  or die(mysql_error());
    while ($f=mysql_fetch_array($re)) {
            $arreglo[]=array('CURP'=>$f['id']);
    }
    if(isset($arreglo)){
        $_SESSION['Usuario']=$arreglo;
        header("Location: ../admin.php");
    }else{
        header("Location: ../login.php?error=datos no validos");
    } ?>

<center><h1>CALIFICACIONES</h1></center>
     <?php mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
     mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); ?>

<div class="wrapper3">
  <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
   <div id="Layer1" style="width:80%; height:200px; overflow:scroll;"> 
     <table width="100%" border="0">
  <?php
    $f['id']=$var_curp ;

         mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
  mysql_connect ("localhost","root","") or die ("No se pudo conectar al servidor");
  mysql_select_db('bdcetis13')or die ('Error al seleccionar la Base de Datos: '.mysql_error());
  $result251=mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM boleta WHERE CURP='$var_curp'");
  $a251 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result251);
  $result261=mysql_num_rows($result251);
  do{
        $curp=$a251['CURP'];
        $mat=$a251['MATERIA'];
        $cali=$a251['CALIFICACION1'];
        $cali2=$a251['CALIFICACION2'];
        $cali3=$a251['CALIFICACION3'];
        $calif=$a251['CALIFICACION_FINAL'];
        $asis1=$a251['ASISTENCIA1'];
        $asis2=$a251['ASISTENCIA2'];
        $asis3=$a251['ASISTENCIA3'];
  ?>
       <tr>
         <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><?php echo $curp;?></td>
         <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><?php echo $mat;?></td>
         <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><?php echo $cali;?></td>
         <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><?php echo $cali2;?></td>
         <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><?php echo $cali3;?></td>
         <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><?php echo $calif;?></td>
         <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><?php echo $asis1;?></td>
         <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><?php echo $asis2;?></td>
         <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><?php echo $asis3;?></td>
       </tr>
       <?php }while($a251 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result251));?>
     </table>
   </div>
  </form>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ES CORRECTO VERIFICAR LAS LLAVES {}

Answer (score 8):

Sí que es difícil encontrar un error de sintaxis en ese montón de líneas. pero parece que en el primer `if` `if(isset($_SESSION['Usuario'])){` abre llaves pero no las cierra nunca . si es su validación  el cierre debe ir después del `</div>`

```
 </div>
 <?php } ?>
```